# I can't find the gem program on RHEL Linux rhel63-1

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

```
OS: Linux rhel63-1 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 15 10:48:38 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
<br>RUBY: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]<p>
```

This my first run at ruby on Linux, so probably I'm missing something obvious. But shouldn't there be a gem program somewhere? 
I can't find it (which,whereis) (I did ruby a few years ago, and a gem program came with it)

```
<p>"sudo find / -name gem" returns one directory named gem with one empty subdir named 'LC_MESSAGES'. 
<br>I tried "yum reinstall ruby", but it says I have the latest version. 
<br>I removed and reinstalled ruby, still no gem
```

I tried "rvm install gem", which complained, and then "rvm all do gem", which didn't complain, but AFAICT didn't do anything.

Any help?

Comment: you do not have rubygems installed. Have a look at http://rubygems.org/pages/download

Comment: thank you! now I have gem. But gem complains about not finding rubygems:  gem install bundler  /usr/local/lib/ruby/rubygems/bin/gem:8:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)  
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/rubygems/bin/gem:8    
[root@rhel63-1 ~]# !ls  
ls -l  /usr/local/lib/ruby/rubygems/lib  
total 44  
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1425 Aug 12 08:38 gauntlet_rubygems.rb  
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root  4096 Aug 12 08:38 rubygems  
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 32462 Aug 12 08:38 rubygems.rb  
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   268 Aug 12 08:38 ubygems.rb

Comment: can you add this into your code

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. Gem doesn't work at all. Every invocation gives me this error.Add what? I'm just trying to download a tool and get it running, so I don't have code. Should I add the path to the rubygems require?

Comment: Whats the error you gen when you try. `rvmsudo gem install rails`

Comment: [root@rhel63-1 ~]# rvmsudo gem install rails   
sudo: gem: command not found  
[root@rhel63-1 ~]# which gem  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/rubygems/bin/gem